# @Input() in Angular2 does not work with string

Tags: angular

Please see below codes :

```ts
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './hello-world/hello-world.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelloWorldComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I added 'HelloWorldComponent' to main component ('AppComponent')

in 'app.component.html'

```ts
<h1>
  {{title}}
  <app-hello-world [name]="test"></app-hello-world> // When [name]="Test" does not works but when I use number works !!! [name] = "4"
</h1>
```

in 'hello-world.component.ts' in used @Input() decorator

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello-world',
  templateUrl: './hello-world.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello-world.component.css']
})
export class HelloWorldComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and in 'hello-world.component.html'

```ts
<p>
{{name}}
</p>
```

Why when I passa string to [name] it does not work ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want is

```
[name]="'test'"
```

or

```
name="test"
```

because without quotes `test` is interpreted as identifier, while `5` isn't (like in normal TS code)

The difference between the two variants is that
the former does property binding and won't show up in the DOM
while the second is a normal HTML attribute that is also read by Angular. It will be added to the DOM as is.

Comment: the needed quotes are because of Typescript or Angular2 ?

Comment: When you add `[]` Angular interprets the value as expression and `test` (without quotes) in TS/JS means the value of the variable `test`. `[name]="test"` (again without quotes) means pass the name of the field `test`  of the components class to the `name` property of the `HelloWorldComponent` component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not referencing any logic that is to be evaluated, you do not need the pointy brackets around the Input() parameter. Just write

name="test"

Comment: Can you explan more about 'not referencing any logic' ?

Comment: What Günther wrote in the other answer. If you add the pointy brackets, you make Angular2 evaluate any expresseion (=logic) inside the quotes.